# Modx организация поиска и фильтрации

Tags: modx, php, cms

День добрый, Уважаемые.
Подскажите пожалуйста какими средствами в modx cmf возможно организовать поиск и фильтрацию туров. например как здесь  [http://www.mk-travel.ru/foreign/toursearch.](http://www.mk-travel.ru/foreign/toursearch)
Хоть что нибудь для опоры дайте, очень.
Заранее благодарю, за неоценимую помощь.
Еще раз спасибо кто помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На приведенном вами сайте установлен поиск туров от http://sletat.ru/ с помощью обычного IFRAME. Чтобы сделать такой или подобный поиск туров придется очень постараться. Лучше уж заключить договора на установку поисков туров от ведущий туроператоров и не париться. Если у вас на сайте не более 500 туров, настолько навороченный поиск вам не понадобится.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ